# Minimum character change requirement during tag-edit

Tags: support, bug

I recently tried to edit https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33521/an-unkown-substance-present-in-urine-with-the-empirical-formula-ch4n2o to remove the incorrect tag (it has been done [now](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/33521/revisions)).

While doing just a tag-edit (i.e. no changes made in the body), I get a notification saying **edits must be 6 characters**. But I didn't edit the body at all. I was trying to make just a tag-edit. Is this a glitch?

I flagged the question for moderator help and got this reply:

> Even if it's just a tag edit, to *suggest* an edit requires the minimum character change.

I still don't understand this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Might be a bug, see the [related discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234345/edit-must-be-at-least-6-characters-but-i-am-retagging) at Meta.SE.

Comment: Judging from [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247036/260760) it should be possible. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184544/260760

Comment: That was my mistake.  As long as you don't touch the body of the post, the edit should go through.  I'm looking into this. CC:@Martin-マーチン

Comment: There appears to be a strange space at the top of that post (see the revision history).  That's the only thing I can think of that would have fooled the system into thinking that you'd edited the body.  I haven't heard anything official yet, though.